# Terminology on Varieties in Classical Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I am self-studying Kaplansky's *Commutative Rings* and don't know anyone who can explain this to me, so I would greatly appreciate **clear solutions and critiques of my attempts** (I know my proofs have some errors). This is 1.3 problem 12. As this is a longer question, please do not hesitate to post answers for specific parts. Thanks a lot!

Let $K$ be a field and write $A_n$ for the vector space of $n$-ples over $K$. Given an ideal $I \subset K[x_1, ..., x_n]$ we write $V(I)$ for the subset of $A_n$ consisting of all points in $A_n$ where all the polynomials in $I$ vanish, and we call such a set a variety. Given a subset $S$ of $A_n$, we write $J(S)$ for the ideal of polynomials vanishing on $S$. Assume $K$ is algebraically closed.

- Prove that $J(V(I))$ is the radical of $I$.
- Prove that the map $S \to J(S)$ sets up a one to one correspondence between all varieties and all radical ideals.
- Prove under set theoretic inclusion that the set of radical ideals is a compelte lattice and that the set of varieties likewise is a complete lattice. Prove further that the correspondence of the previous part is order-inverting.
- In the lattice of varieties of the previous part, prove that the union of a finite number of varieties is just the set theoretic union.
- Prove that in the correspondence of the second bullet point an ideal is prime if and only if the correspondince variety is irreducible in the sense that it cannot be exhibited as the union of two properly smaller varieties.

Theorem 33: Let $K$ be algebraically closed and $f, g_1, ..., g_r  \in K[x_1, ..., x_n]$. Assume that $f$ vanishes at the common zeros of $g_1, ..., g_r$. Then some power of $f$ lies in the ideal $(g_1,..., g_r)$.

Proof of part a: Let $I=(g_1, ... ,g_r)$. The common zeros of $g_1, ..., g_r$ are denoted by $V(I)$. Let $f$ be a polynomial that vanishes on the set $V(I)$. Then some power of $f$ lies in $I$ by Theorem 33 (above). Hence $f \in J(V(I))$.

Proof of part b: If $V(I) = \{a_1, ..., a_n\}$ then each element of $J(V(I))$ would have the form $p(x)(x-a_1)\cdots (x-a_n)$. Hence we could have the injection $a_i \mapsto \Pi_{k=1}^n (x-a_k)$.

Proof of part c: In exercise 9b, it was proven that every radical ideal can be expressed as the intersection of maximal ideals. Hence any set of radical ideals can be expressed as the intersection of maximal ideals and therefore it has its supremum and infimum.

Proof of part d:  Not sure. I have never worked with lattices before. Please explain.

Proof of part e: Suppose that $I \subset K[x_1, ..., x_n]$ is prime and $fg \in I$. Let $A_0$ be the set of zeros of $f$. Since $I$ is prime, either $f \in I$ or $g \in I$. Without loss of generality, let $f \in I$. In that case, $V(I)\subset A_0$. Perhaps $f$ is not irreducible, that is, $f=f_1f_2$. Without loss of generality, $f_1 \in I$. Denote the set of zeros of $f_1$ by $A_1$. It follows that $V(I) \subset A_1 \subset A_0$. We can repeat this procedure finitely many times, exploiting the fact that $I$ is prime. It follows that $V(I) \subset A_k \subset \cdots \subset A_1 \subset A_0$. This implies that $V(I) \subset S$ where $S$ is the set of zeros of an irreducible factor of $f$. Because this factor is irreducible, if we split $V(I)$ into two proper subsets, then these subsets will not be varieties. Hence $V(I)$ is irreducible, as desired.

Now, we prove the other direction. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $V(I)$ is irreducible but $I$ is not prime. Then there exist $f,g \in K[x_1, ..., x_n]$ such that $fg \in I$ but $f \notin I $ and $g \notin I$. This implies that either $V(I) \cap V((f)) = \emptyset$ or $V((f)) \subset V(I)$ and that $V(I) \cap V((g)) = \emptyset$ or $V((g)) \subset V(I)$. Because $fg \in I$, $V(I) \subset V((f)) \cup V((g))$.

If $V((f)) \subset V(I)$ then $V(I)= V((f))$ and $V((g))\subset V((f))$. This implies that $f \in I$, which is a contradiction. Similarly, it cannot be the case that $V((g)) \subset V(I)$. Therefore, $V(I) \cap V((f)) = \emptyset $ and $V(I) \cap V((g)) = \emptyset$, which contradict $V(I) \subset V((f)) \cup V((g))$. So, we have proven that $V(I)$ is irreducible implies that $I$ is prime. This completes the proof.